# How to correctly place "plaza" in a store name?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-order

The word "plaza" is actually a Spanish word and had been adopted by major English dictionaries.

My issue is that I don't know how to correctly place the word in a store name. For example, if I want to use the word to name a store which sells bikes and bike accessories, should I name the store "Bike Plaza" or "Plaza Bike"?

I did some searches on Google and saw both usages. I hope to figure out the best usage.

Comment: It's a name. It can be anything you want. There can be no objective answer to this without more information about what your criteria are. Both versions of the store name are ambiguous and can be interpreted in multiple ways. (Which components are proper nouns and which common nouns?) Using a longer name would remove ambiguity. For example, *Bikes in the Plaza*, *Plaza's Bikes*, and *The Bike Plaza*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bike Plaza** would indicate that the plaza focused on bikes or was intended for cyclists.

**Plaza Bike** would indicate an establishment in the plaza that dealt with bikes.

So, if you need to choose between the two, the latter is what you want.